# How to group wallpapers/photos according to their colors?

Tags: command-line, desktop-customization

I have several workspaces and I'd like them to be distinguishable by the wallpapers.

On the other hand, I'd like to have some form of wallpaper rotation on each workspace.

Is there any ready software, that can take my wallpapers as input, and group them into specified number of groups by their color?

Extra bonus if it would work from command line (so I can automate it).

Answer (score 0):

I've scribed the following script with R:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

makeSureInstalled<-function(package) {if (length(grep(paste("^",package,"$",sep=""),noquote(installed.packages())[,1]))==0) install.packages(package)
                                      library(package=package,character.only=TRUE)
}

makeSureInstalled("argparse")
makeSureInstalled("foreach")
makeSureInstalled("doMC")

arghandling<-function()
  # Reads command line arguments, verifies the input
{
  parser <- ArgumentParser(description="Reads all files in the specified directory (not-recursively) treats them as jpegs, and groups them by mean color.",
                           epilog="Example: ./wallpapers-grouping.R --cluster-count 9 --out-prefix 'cluster '")
  parser$add_argument("--cluster-count","-n", type="integer", dest="clustercount",
                      help="Number of groups to do. Must be (much) smaller than number of individual photos.")
  parser$add_argument("--feature-set", "-f", dest="mode", type="integer", 
                      help="Before running the actual clustering, the program pre-processes image and extracts features. There are 2 feature sets supported: 1 - one pixel (3 numbers for each colour). 2 - 4 pixel (image is divided into equal 4 parts, and each part is averaged to one pixel. 4x3=12 numbers in total.)")
  parser$add_argument("--out-prefix","-o", type="character", default='cluster ', dest='prefix',
                      help="The prefix appended to each grouped picture before grouping. Can be a directory name (absolute or relative) or name prefix.")
  parser$add_argument("--cpu-count",  type="integer", dest="cpu",
                      help="How many cores to use. Defaults to all available cores.")
  parser$add_argument("input", type="character", 
                      help="Input directory. Defaults to current directory. ")

  args<-commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

  if (length(args)==0)
  {
    parser$print_help()
    quit()
  } else
  {
    cat("Welcome to the wallpapers-grouping.R program.\n")
    args=parser$parse_args(args)
  }


  if (is.null(args$clustercount))
  {
    cat(paste0("Error! You must specify number of clusters with --cluster-count or -n argument.\n"))
    quit()    
  }

  if (is.null(args$input))
  {
    args$input<-cwd()
  } else {
    if(!file.exists(args$input))
    {
      cat(paste0("Cannot find the input directory (", args$input,")\n"))
      quit()
    }
  }

  photos=dir(path=args$input)
  cat(paste0(length(photos)," files found in ",args$input,".\n"))

  if (length(photos)<=args$clustercount)
  {
    cat(paste0("Number of clusters must be (much) smaller than number of photos.\n"))
    quit()
  }

  registerDoMC()
  howManyCores<-getDoParWorkers()
  if(is.null(args$cpu) || args$cpu==howManyCores)
  {
    cat(paste0(howManyCores," cores detected.\n"))
  } else {
    cat(paste0(howManyCores," cores detected, but will use ",args$cpu," independent threads.\n"))  
    howManyCores<-args$cpu
  }
  registerDoMC(cores=howManyCores)

  if(is.null(args$mode))
  {
    args$mode<-1
  }

  args$mode<-switch(args$mode,1,2)

  list(args=args,photos=photos)
}

ah<-arghandling()

photos<-ah$photos
args<-ah$args


makeSureInstalled('jpeg')
makeSureInstalled('plyr')

processphoto<-function(filename,mode=1) {
  photo=readJPEG(filename)
  if(mode==1)
  {
    apply(photo,3,mean)
  }else  {
    dims<-dim(obraz)[1:2]
    gr=round(dims/2)
    o11<-photo[1:gr[[1]],1:gr[[2]],]
    o12<-photo[(gr[[1]]+1):dims[[1]],1:gr[[2]],]
    o21<-photo[1:gr[[1]],(gr[[2]]+1):dims[[2]],]
    o22<-photo[(gr[[1]]+1):dims[[1]],(gr[[2]]+1):dims[[2]],]
    o11<-apply(o11,3,mean)
    o12<-apply(o12,3,mean)
    o21<-apply(o21,3,mean)
    o22<-apply(o22,3,mean)

    c(o11,o12,o21,o22)
  }
}

cat(paste0('Extracting features from all ',length(photos),' pictures...'))
results<-aaply(photos,1,processphoto,.parallel=TRUE,mode=args$mode)

cat(paste0('Grouping them into ',length(args$clustercount),' groups using k-means...'))
clusters<-kmeans(results,args$clustercount)

copycluster <- function(which.cluster) {
  files<-photos[clusters$cluster==which.cluster]
  todir <- paste0(args$prefix,which.cluster)
  if (!isTRUE(file.info(todir)$isdir)) dir.create(todir, recursive=TRUE)

  file.copy(from = files,  to = paste0(todir,'/',files ))
}

cat(paste0("Copying photos into their groups..."))
a_ply(1:args$clustercount,1,copycluster)
```

The scripts installs required libraries. On Linux/Mac it will use all available cores (on Windows, unfortunately it can't).

It should work out-of-the-box on any system, and on Linux/Mac, thanks for the shebang, it can be run directly from the terminal.